# Dark matter vs black holes

Tags: black-holes, dark-matter

I want to think simple in the way black holes and dark matter interact with matter.

Whats differences exists between dark matter particle and a quantum description of a black hole full of dark matter?

Whats differences exists between a very small black hole (in the limits of General Relativity) and a dark matter particle?

Comment: We do not know what dark matter is, so any answer would be constrained by this.  A quantum description of a black hole is also beyond what accepted mainstream theory can achieve.

Comment: But we have some hints how they interact with matter. It is acceptable think in it even if could easily be unproductive.

Answer (score 1):

Because the physical evidence for dark matter is its calculated gravitational effects, then it may be assumed that dark matter behaves similarly to baryonic matter with respect to the black hole.  This follows because we have only a single theory of gravity that requires the identical behavior of all kinds of mass.

We can speculate on differences.  Because the properties of dark matter are unknown, the details related to such principles as conservation of information cannot be assessed.  In addition, as it approaches the black hole it may not show the same radiative behavior as baryonic matter.

Once the dark matter is within the black hole, I don't believe there are physics to describe any difference between it and baryonic matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well a black hole made of dark matter or ordinary matter should behave similarly because the only properties black holes conserve are charge, mass, and spin. Any other properties are lost to the universe according to some theories. There are ideas that other types of information might be hidden on the surface of a black hole. Dark matter would act like black holes because they both have gravity. Maybe the distribution for that gravity might change however. They might be identical. However a dark matter particle for what I know might interact with the weak force. Though mostly through gravity.